# SQL: Create view by counting grouped items that belong to specific category

Tags: sql, view

A simplified version of my database looks like in the table below. The database contains songs from polls for which the user has voted. There are multiple polls available, and some songs may belong to several polls.

Simplified example:

```
+------+------------------------------------+
| POLL | SONG                               | 
+------+------------------------------------+
|  1   | ABBA - I HAVE A DREAM              |
|  1   | 10 CC - DREADLOCK HOLIDAY          |
|  1   | ABBA - I HAVE A DREAM              |
|  1   | ABBA - I HAVE A DREAM              |
|  1   | ANDREA BERG - WENN DU MICH WILLST  |
|  2   | QUEEN - WE WILL ROCK YOU           | 
|  2   | ABBA - I HAVE A DREAM              |
|  2   | QUEEN - WE WILL ROCK YOU           | 
|  2   | HELEN SHAPIRO - QUEEN FOR TONIGHT  |
|  3   | ABBA - I HAVE A DREAM              |
+------+------------------------------------+
```

The SQL script below creates a view across all the polls, and counts ALL the songs for which the users have voted (doesn't take into account the poll).

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW `voteResults` AS
SELECT
  poll,
  song,
  COUNT(song) AS count
FROM votes
GROUP BY song
ORDER BY count DESC
```

I need to however find a way to count the songs that belong to each poll, so the view should have an output like this:

```
+------+------------------------------------+-------+
| POLL | SONG                               | COUNT |
+------+------------------------------------+-------+
|  1   | ABBA - I HAVE A DREAM              |   3   |
|  1   | 10 CC - DREADLOCK HOLIDAY          |   1   |
|  1   | ANDREA BERG - WENN DU MICH WILLST  |   1   |
|  2   | QUEEN - WE WILL ROCK YOU           |   2   |
|  2   | ABBA - I HAVE A DREAM              |   1   |
|  2   | HELEN SHAPIRO - QUEEN FOR TONIGHT  |   1   |
|  3   | ABBA - I HAVE A DREAM              |   1   |
+------+------------------------------------+-------+
```

How can this best be achieved?

Comment: You typically `GROUP BY` the same columns as you `SELECT`, _except those who are arguments to set functions_.

Comment: You are trying to count the songs that belongs to each poll. Have you tried grouping your view by **poll,song**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use group by (poll, song) instead of group by song will give you the result you want.

Based on your example output, you probably also want to sort by (poll, count desc), instead (count desc) alone.

Here is the [query](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/6de9a/1):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW `voteResults` AS
SELECT
    poll,
    song,
COUNT(song) AS count
FROM votes
GROUP BY poll, song
ORDER BY poll, count DESC
```

| poll | song | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ABBA - I HAVE A DREAM | 3 |
| 1 | ANDREA BERG - WENN DU MICH WILLST | 1 |
| 1 | 10 CC - DREAMLOCK HOLIDAY | 1 |
| 2 | QUEEN - WE WILL ROCK YOU | 2 |
| 2 | HELEN SHAPIRO - QUEEN FOR TONIGHT | 1 |
| 2 | ABBA - I HAVE A DREAM | 1 |
| 3 | ABBA - I HAVE A DREAM | 1 |